# Solution of equation $z=a((x-a)e^{2x/a}+x+a)$

Tags: education

I want to solve the equation for $x$

$a((x-a)e^{2x/a}+x+a)-z=0$

Conditions on $a$ and $z$ are: $a,z>0$ and both real.

I made some research but couldn't find a lot. Maybe something with the Lambert W function?

In general, I'm interested in solutions of equations of the form

$a=xe^x+bx$